# Redis GEORADIUS with one ZSET versus a lot of ZSETs of particular size

Tags: data-structures, redis, gps, geospatial

What will work faster, one big ZSET with geodata where I'll query for 100m radius with GEORADIUS

OR

a lot of ZSETs where each ZSET is responsible for 100m X 100m square covering the whole world? and named after this 100m squares like:

left_corner1_49_2440000_28_5010000

left_corner2_49_2450000_28_5010000

.......

and have all the 100 meters to the right and bottom inside the sets.
So when searching for the nearest point I'll just omit the redundant digits from gps like: 49.2440408, 28.5011694 will become
49.2440000, 28.5010000 so this way I'll know the ZSETS's name where just to get all the exact values with 100 meters precision.

OR to question it in general form: how are the ZSET's names are stored and accessed in redis? If I have too much ZSETS will it impact performance while accessing them?

Comment: Why not benchmark it and find out? One point in favor of the more complex, multi-zset approach is the ability to somewhat parallelize it by using a sharded/clustered environment.

Answer (score 1):

Precise comparison of this approaches could only be done via benchmark and it would be specific to your dataset and configuration. But architecturally speaking, your pros and cons are:

- **BIG ZSET**: less bandwidth and less operations (CPU cycles) taken to execute, no problems on borders (possible duplicates with many ZSETS), can get throughput with sharding;
- **MANY ZSETS**: less latency for other operations (while big ZSET is going, other commands are waiting), can get throughput with sharding AND latency with clustering.

As for bottom line question, I did not see implementation code, but set names should be the same keys as any other keys you use. This is what [Redis FAQ](https://redis.io/topics/faq) says about number of keys:

> **What is the maximum number of keys a single Redis instance can hold? <...>**
>
> Redis can handle up to 2^32 keys, and was tested in practice to handle
>   at least 250 million keys per instance.

**UPDATE:**

Look at what Redis docs say about GEORADIUS:

> Time complexity: O(N+log(M)) where N is the number of elements inside
>   the bounding box of the circular area delimited by center and radius
>   and M is the number of items inside the index.

It means that items outside of your query make O(log(M)) impact on your query. So, 17 hops for 10m items or 21 hop for 1b items which is quite affordable. The question left is will you do partitioning between nodes?

Comment: @MidnightGuest I've updated the answer and it should be enough to make a decision